# Using custom LaTex packages in Facebook Messenger

Tags: packages

It is common knowledge that Facebook Messenger [supports](https://www.facebook.com/help/147348452522644) LaTex formatting on its web clients (facebook.com and messenger.com). As it is mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/6ug91z/facebook_messenger_now_renders_basic_latex/), Facebook uses a version of [KaTex](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/) to render all Tex input. It supports a wide variety of basic LaTex functions and some features of a couple of Maths and formatting-related packages.

**Is it possible to use any other packages with KaTex, especially in Facebook Messenger?**

Comment: common knowledge? I didn't know the FB app could do that.

Comment: I didn't think I'd raise awareness of this feature by writing this question, but all the better

Comment: Questions about MathJax are normally considered to be off-topic on this site. While these tools support the input format of LaTeX they don't actually render what they print in TeX or LaTeX. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3482/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/272/35864. Stackoverflow has a KaTeX tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/katex. KaTeX seems to be similar in its aims to MathJax, so it is not unlikely to be off-topic as well.

Comment: I checked it, and I know this doesn't change anything, but KaTex doesn't use MathJax but its proprietary rendering engine. Sorry if this is considered off-topic, I didn't know about said meta question at the time of posting the question

Comment: Well, things like this are only borderline off-topic anyway. As far as I can see KaTeX does not use TeX to render its input, so I seriously doubt that you can load arbitrary packages. Maybe the developers support some features of packages other than `amsmath` or the (La)TeX kernel math, but I think it is unlikely that you would get full `mhchem` support.

Comment: I voted to close because off-topic. Nevertheless, I like that I now know about this FB feature! :)

Comment: In particular see https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/wiki/Examining-TeX where it says that KaTeX is supposed to be compatible with TeX/LaTeX. It is not based on TeX and only emulates some of its behaviour. https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/issues/793, https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/wiki/Package-Emulation might also be of interest